# new button is not respnding to .click

Tags: jquery

This button should create a button witch can create another button and so on.
But for some reason The created buttons don´t respond to the .click function.

```
<button> old Button works</button>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $(this).after("<button> new button doesn´t work</button>");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works now.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
    $(this).after("<button> new button work</button>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button> old Button works</button>
```